# How to concatenate ndrarray with different dimensions(shape)?

Tags: numpy, stack, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I have two data which type is ndarray.
I want to merge X_train and Y_train, but they are have different shape.
I try to use concatenate, stack but it show me same error.

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(type(X_train[1]))
print(Y_train.shape)
print(type(Y_train[1]))

(17731, 30, 14, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(17731, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

x_train_tt = np.stack([X_train , Y_train])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-74b8e20eca7c> in <module>

----> 3 x_train_tt = np.stack([X_train , Y_train])

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvironment2.3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    424     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
    425     if len(shapes) != 1:
--> 426         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
    427 
    428     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1

ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Is there any solution?

I want to get shape like that

**x_train_tt.shape
(17731,30,15,1)**

Comment: `np.stack` is a way of using np.concatenate` to join 2 or more arrays along a new axis.  So yes,  those arrays have to have the same shape.  Why do you want to concatenate these 2 arrays - in what ever way? Except for the first dimension ('batch'?) they don't share dimensions.

Comment: You could replicate `Y_train` 30 times to make a `(17731,30,1,1)` array, and then do a concatenate on the `-2` axis.  But again, why?  I assume `Y_train` is a label value (integer?, string) one for each of the 17731 'images' of `X_train`, where an image is (30,14,1) shaped.   Sometimes data like this loaded from a 2d `csv`, where `Y` is one column, and `X` is flattened to 30*14 columns (and 1000s of rows).

Comment: Thank yo for your answering. 
My dataset is signal data and their row shape is (20631, 15)
I want to use 2D-CNN to predict cycles(Y_train means cycle, so it has 1 columns) 
For using 2D-CNN in that data, I need to reshape that data for 4D tensor.

Comment: For that, I find some papers that mention about the time-window approach. So I reshape that that into (17731, 30, 14,1) -> in here 30 means time window length! So (30,14,1) is not an image. 
Then, I have X_train and Y_train. Now, I want to merge [X_train, Y_train] because I want to make "cycle" feature in x_train_tt.